# Which is the better document structure?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am developing several React Projects like below that.

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, getElementById("root"));
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <header>header</header>
    <main>main</main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

when I built above them, I could get output like below that.

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <header>header</header>
      <main>main</main>
      <footer>footer</footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I wonder whether this **Markup Structure** is okay.

Because the `<body />` tag has `<div id="root" />` and it has `<header />` and `<main />` and `<footer />`.

I thought it should be changed like below that.

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <header>header</header>
    <main>main</main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

so, I tried to change my codes like below that.

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

ReactDOM.render(<Header />, getElementById("header"));
ReactDOM.render(<App />, getElementById("root"));
ReactDOM.render(<footer />, getElementById("footer"));
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
const App = () => (<>App</>);
const Header = () => (<>Header</>);
const Footer = () => (<>Footer</>);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <header id="header"></header>
    <main id="root"></main>
    <footer id="footer"></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to know which structure(?) is better and why.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Rob Incorrect - the suggested App.js above is objectively the wrong way to bootstrap a React app. It doesn't provide any way to share state between the OPs main app parts - it effectively bootstraps 3 separate apps, instead of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React tells us why we shouldn't use `<body>` as the container to mount our App on:

If you try this:

```
const rootElement = document.body;
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You will get this warning:

> **Warning:** render(): Rendering components directly into document.body is discouraged, since its children are often manipulated by third-party scripts and browser extensions. This may lead to subtle reconciliation issues. Try rendering into a container element created for your app.

That's why you should stick to the root `<div id="root">`

It will not hurt your website semantic.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

> **Examples of non-semantic elements:**  and  - Tells nothing about its content

**NOTE:** if you do the way that you're suggesting, you'll be needing to mount 3 different components. One for the `header`, one for the `main` and one for the `footer`. How would you share state between them? How would the `header` component be aware of the `state` changes that happen on the `body` component and vice-versa?

From https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html :

> Remember: **React is all about one-way data flow down the component hierarchy.** It may not be immediately clear which component should own what state. This is often the most challenging part for newcomers to understand, so follow these steps to figure it out:
>
> For each piece of state in your application:
>
> - Identify every component that renders something based on that state.
> - Find a common owner component **(a single component above all the components that need the state in the hierarchy)**.
> - Either the common owner or another component higher up in the hierarchy should own the state.
> - If you can’t find a component where it makes sense to own the state, create a new component simply for holding the state and add it somewhere in the hierarchy above the common owner component.

Answer (score 1):

What are you worried about, the `div` wrapping your app? There's no problem with that at all. `div` (and `span`) are non-semantic elements, so they don't have any effect on the document structure as such.

This is wrong, don't start your React app like this :)

```
ReactDOM.render(<Header />, getElementById("header"));
ReactDOM.render(<App />, getElementById("root"));
ReactDOM.render(<footer />, getElementById("footer"));
```

It bootstraps three separate apps with no way to idiomatically share state amongst them.